# Is it possible to resize a gameobject in Unity permanently?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm just starting to learn how to build a game in Unity. I built a player gameobject that can move and has animations.  When I tried to build the map I found that the player was far too small. I tried to change its scale but when I ran the game it returned to the original size. How can it be resized permanently?

Comment: I believe the scale  has keyframe in animation, so every time you run it, the scale resets to what is keyframed in animation clip. Please consider changing the scale in your animation clip. Hope it helps

Comment: another option is rescale your map (just to add a choice)

Answer (score -1):

Try resizing the gameobject when the scene is not running. Your game cannot be edited while it is in test mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).